# Seelog rollingfile filename pattern not as expected

Tags: logging, go

I have a seelog config file like

```
<seelog minlevel="info">
    <outputs>
        <console />
        <rollingfile type="date" datepattern="060201" filename="/tmp/-myApp.log" maxrolls="5" archivetype="none"/>
    </outputs>
</seelog>
```

What comes out are files like /tmp/-myApp.log.142711, I expected /tmp/142711-myApp.log as it is suggested at https://github.com/cihub/seelog/wiki/Receiver-reference qoute:

```
* In case of 'date' rolling, the file names will be formed this way:
   time.Now().Format(rollfileWriter.datePattern)+" "+rollFileWriter.fileName)
```

Can my expected behaviour be achieved somehow? Am I thinking in the wrong way?

Comment: Off-Topic. Seelog Bug Report. [Seelog rollingfile filename pattern not as expected #71](https://github.com/cihub/seelog/issues/71)

Comment: @peterSO I did not even know whether this was a bug before the developer answered on github... There is no need to downvote. You could just have commented and request a close.

Comment: I did vote to close and gave an explicit reason. The StackOverflow close vote process automatically generated my comment. Even after you discovered that this was a seelog bug, you left this question open. Wasting other people's time deserves a downvote. Be more considerate of others; they are unpaid volunteers whose time is valuable.

Comment: Come on, it's not my only occupation to code. I do check those issues daily any that's why I closed this issue the same day I noted the comment of the dev. I will not waste my time further discussing with you, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a developer states in https://github.com/cihub/seelog/issues/71 this unexpected behaviour results from a outdated documentation and may be addressed in the future. A "fix" to get the desired behaviour is not yet available.